# how to write test class from Apex ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery?

Tags: apex, unit-test, einstein-analytics

How to write the Apex test class for ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery?

```
ConnectApi.LiteralJson result = ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(JSONString);
```

Comment: One way/workaround is - To have seeAllData true, so that you'll see the data. AFAIK, it doesn't have mock provided.